# Alternative approach to reference geometry to mirror a swept cut

Tags: solidworks

I am looking for a way to mirror the swept cut shown in the figure below about the object's midplane, which is parallel to the right plane. Can you do this without reference geometry, for example is there a way to select the midplane of the object without creating a new plane?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there needs to be a physical plane or face to select for the mirror to be defined.

You can define the reference plane to be the mid-plane between two opposing faces, or to be on a central axis etc. such that the position of the mirror plane dynamically updates if/when the geometry changes.